# Selecting minimum value, getting Invalid relational operator

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am having trouble with a basic SQL query. It happens when using the MIN function with a join.

What I am trying to do is to select the customer with the smallest order while also displaying there details.

The error that arises is an invalid operator from the function below:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.FNAME, CUST_ORDER.SALE_PRICE FROM (CUSTOMER INNER JOIN CUST_ORDER ON CUST_ORDER.CUST_NBR=CUSTOMER.CUST_NBR)HAVING MIN(CUST_ORDER.SALE_PRICE);

+----------+-------+-------+
| CUST_NBR | FNAME | LNAME |
+----------+-------+-------+
+-----------+----------+------------+
| ORDER_NUM | CUST_NUM | SALE_PRICE |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
+-------+------------+
| FNAME | SALE_PRICE |
+-------+------------+
```

Which should only return the a single user with their name a the sale price.

I have also tried

```
HAVING SALE_PRICE = MIN(SALE_PRICE)
```

But this throws up a group by error. I have also tried it with a group by clause:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.FNAME, CUST_ORDER.SALE_PRICE FROM (CUSTOMER INNER JOIN CUST_ORDER ON CUST_ORDER.CUST_NBR=CUSTOMER.CUST_NBR) GROUP BY FNAME HAVING MIN(CUST_ORDER.SALE_PRICE);
```

which gives and invalid operator error as well.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

**NOTE**

If i take out the `HAVING min(sale_price)` from the original query it returns the list of all users and all the orders. I presumed the having min would just leave me with the one smallest order why is it giving an error?

**UPDATE**

I have included the solution the comments suggested, but this returns the smallest order for each user, i want the smallest order across all users which should only return one customer.

Comment: Don't forget the GROUP BY!

Comment: Error is caused by two things, first `min(sale_price)` it is not a condition, should be `sale_price = min(sale_price)`, and second you need a group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.FNAME, CUST_ORDER.SALE_PRICE
  FROM (SELECT CUSTOMER.FNAME,
               CUST_ORDER.SALE_PRICE,
               MIN (CUST_ORDER.SALE_PRICE) OVER () MIN_PRICE
          FROM (CUSTOMER
                INNER JOIN CUST_ORDER
                   ON CUST_ORDER.CUST_NBR = CUSTOMER.CUST_NBR))
 WHERE CUST_ORDER.SALE_PRICE = MIN_PRICE
```

Also you can get the minium with a subquery and then ask for it:

```
 SELECT CUSTOMER.FNAME, CUST_ORDER.SALE_PRICE
    FROM (CUSTOMER
          INNER JOIN CUST_ORDER ON CUST_ORDER.CUST_NBR = CUSTOMER.CUST_NBR)
    where CUST_ORDER.SALE_PRICE = (SELECT MIN(SALE_PRICE) FROM CUST_ORDER)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with analytic (window) functions instead of aggregates:

```
SELECT fname, sale_price FROM (
    SELECT c.fname, co.sale_price, RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY co.sale_price ) rn
      FROM customer c INNER JOIN cust_order co
        ON c.cust_nbr = co.cust_nbr
) WHERE rn = 1;
```

This will return **all** customers with the minimum order sale price; if you want just one customer with the minimum, use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()`.